# Not sure how to go about this group theory proof

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Prove that if $f : G \rightarrow H$ is a group isomorphism, then for any element $x \in G$ one has $o(x) = o(f(x))$, where $o(a)$ denotes the order of the element $a$.

I feel that this proof should be online somewhere but haven't been able to find anything so would be helpful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Before going online, have you tried anything?

Comment: My lecturers have been on strike so have not been teaching the course. I am still expected to hand in assignments though so I thought I would reach out to people who know what they are doing

Comment: Why don't you first learn to google yourself? I found directly [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024799/is-it-true-that-an-isomorphism-maps-elements-of-the-same-order-to-each-other).

Comment: I did try googling but the wording is obviously differen,t thank you though

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way through:

Suppose $f:G\to H$ is a homomorphism with $f(g)=h$

If the order of $g$ is $n$ so that $g^n=1_G$ (with $1_G$ the group identity in $G$) and the order of $h$ is $m$, do you know how to prove that $n$ is an integer multiple of $m$ ie $m|n$ or $n=km$ for some integer $k$? That is straightforward.

Then for an isomorphism, you have homomorphisms in both directions. Hence both $m|n$ and $n|m$ and for positive integers this implies $n=m$.