# Proof verification: For isomorphism $\phi: G\to H$, show that $|\phi (a)|=|a|$ for all $a\in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, group-isomorphism

Could someone please verify my following proof?

> For isomorphism $\phi: G\to H$ of the groups $G$ and $H$, show that $|\phi (a)|=|a|$ for all $a\in G$.

**Proof:** Let $a\in G$ with $|a|=n$. Then $a^{n}=e_{G}$, the identity of $G$. Let $|\phi(a)|=m$. Then $(\phi (a))^{m}=e_{H}$, the identity of $H$, or $\phi (a^{m})=e_{H}$. Since $\phi(e_{G})=e_{H}$, it must be that $a^{m}=e_{G}$. Then it must be that $m=n$. Therefore, $|\phi (a)|=|a|$ for all $a\in G$.

Comment: $a^n=e$ does not mean that $a$ has order $n$. Take $a=e$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Hello, thank you for your reply. Could you please explain further? I do not understand as I am new to this subject.

Comment: Did you read the answer by Mark Bennet? This explains it all. What do you not understand? That $a^n=e$ is something else than $|a|=n$? Then read again the definition of $|a|$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde What if I am already assuming that $|a|=n$? Does it then follow that $a^{n}=e_{G}$?

Comment: Yes, it does. But it also could follow $a^{k}=e$ for some other $k$ as well, consider $a=e$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Then I don't see how your comment nor the marked duplicate are helpful to my question, because I assumed the order of $|a|$. Could you please explain further why my proof is wrong?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Oh, I see now. Then what do you suggest I can do to improve my proof?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Is Mark's answer the right way to go about this then?

Comment: Yes, do it like Mark did, concluding $m\mid n$ and $n\mid m$, which gives $n=m$. You conclude from $a^m=a^n=e$ that $m=n$, which is not correct.

Comment: Okay, thank you for correcting my proof. I will do what he did.

Comment: @DietrichBurde What do you think of this solution? ( https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2024810)